# Fortran syntax for assignments

Tags: syntax, fortran, variable-assignment

The Fortran syntax is driving me mad! Can anyone explain how I can *call* the assignment (I'm pretty sure that is not the right terminology either...). I'm trying to **assign a type according to the value type**. I have the following:

```
module test_module

   implicit none

   type :: mytype

      integer   :: i
      real      :: r
      logical   :: l

   contains

      generic :: assignment(=) => mytype_to_type
      procedure, pass(me) :: mytype_to_type

   end type mytype

contains

   subroutine mytype_to_type(t, me)

      implicit none

      class(*), intent(inout)   :: t
      class(mytype), intent(in) :: me

      !.. process based on input type
      select type (t)
         type is (integer)
            t = me%i
         type is (real)
            t = me%r
         type is (logical)
            t = me%l
         class default
            stop "none"
            return
      end select

   end subroutine mytype_to_type

end module test_module

program test

    use test_module

    implicit none

    type(mytype) :: t_type

    integer :: i = 1
    real    :: r = 1.
    logical :: l = .true.

    t_type = i                 !! how is this supposed to work?

    select type(t_type)

        type is (integer)
            write(*,*) "is int"
        type is (real)
            write(*,*) "is real"
        type is (logical)
            write(*,*) "is logical"
        class default
            return

    end select


end program test
```

Would this even work? Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get a compiler error? Share it!

Comment: You do not have any defined assignment from integer to my_type. Only from my_type to class(*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do not quite understand, sorry! Maybe I should clarify what I am trying to do: I want to return a type based on the input type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a subroutine supporting defined assignment the two arguments are such that the first corresponds to the left-hand side of the assignment statement and the second the right-hand side.<sup>1</sup>

Here, then the subroutine you provide is assignment from a `my_type` expression to an unlimited polymorphic object.  This isn't what you want, seeing `t_type` on the left.

Instead, you should provide defined assignment *to* a `my_type` object.

```
subroutine stuff_to_mytype(me,t)
  class(mytype), intent(out) :: me
  class(*), intent(in) :: t

  !.. process based on input type
  select type (t)
     type is (integer)
        me%i = t
     type is (real)
        me%r = t
     type is (logical)
        me%l = t
     class default
        stop "none"
        return
  end select

end subroutine stuff_to_mytype
```

That said, you could do this with a specific subroutine for each type you support, rather than an unlimited polymorphic right-hand side, with generic resolution.  In this case you could also consider generic structure constructors (`t_type=mytype(i)`).

---

<sup>1</sup> Precisely, the second argument is the right-hand side enclosed in parentheses.